# Deleting and replacing entries in a table using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, sql-delete

I have a mammal attribute table with the following elements;

```
MammalAttributeID AttributeID MammalID
```

Some mammals have an attribute record of "cat" (AttributeID 234) , some have an attribute record of "feline" (AttributeID 456) and some have both "feline" and "cat" attribute records.

We want to replace the attribute of "cat" with "feline" in the mammal attribute table and remove the "cat" attribute. So if a mammal has only the "feline" attribute record it remains unchanged. If it has both "cat" and "feline" attribute records entries the "cat" attribute record is deleted.

If it has only the "cat" attribute record a "feline" attribute record is inserted and the "cat" attribute record is deleted.

I can't wrap my brain around the SQL necessary to do this. Can some SQL expert point me in the right direction?

Comment: I would just do this in two passes. First update every cat attribute to feline. Then delete the duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Olgas response would miss the case where a mammal is a cat but not a feline because the delete happens first.

```
--update cats to felines
Update "mammal attribute table"
set AttributeID = 456 
where AttributeID=234

go 

--delete cat attribute
delete from attributetable where AttributeID=234
go 

--delete duplicate feline attribute
delete 
from "mammal attribute table" 
where mammalattributeid in(
        select max(mammalattributeid)
        from "mammal attribute table" 
        group by mammalid,attributeid
        having count(*)>1)
```

Comment: +1 but note that your UPDATE statement would effectively result in duplicate `MammalID, AttributeID` entries temporarily. As the OP has accepted your answer, I guess they had no unique constraint on that pair of columns, but in a saner environment your approach wouldn't work. Also, maybe I am missing something there but I don't see any issue with Olga's approach: the DELETE does happen first but it only deletes the 234 attribute from the mammals that also have the 456 attribute and the UPDATE statement replaces the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Delete rows with 'cat' attribute for mammals that have 'feline' attribute too.

```
DELETE FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
WHERE MammalID in 
(SELECT MammalID FROM [YOUR_TABLE] WHERE AttributeID = 234 -- cat
INTERSECT
SELECT MammalID FROM [YOUR_TABLE] WHERE AttributeID = 456) --feline
AND AttributeID = 234
```

Step 2. Replace all remains 'cat' with 'feline'

```
UPDATE [YOUR_TABLE]
SET AttributeID = 456 
WHERE AttributeID = 234
```

Comment: Uh, wouldn't that nuke both attributes for mammals that have both cat and feline? We want those to end up with only a feline attribute, not no attribute at all.

Comment: The inner 'select' gets rows for which we have **both** attriburtes only, and then outer 'delete' removes "cats" only for these cases. It will not delete 'cat' attributes for mammals that have not 'feline' attribute.

Comment: +1 and the subselect could actually be just `(SELECT MammalID FROM [YOUR_TABLE] WHERE AttributeID = 456)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are in different columns, you'll need to normalize the first column, so they are all the same, then just delete the other one.

```
Update [table] set [attribute1] = 'cat' where [attribute1]='feline' or [attribute2]='cat'
```

Then, delete all the others:

```
delete from [table] where [attribute2]='feline' or [attribute2]='cat'
```

That should do it.

Comment: No, there are no repeating columns, that would break normalization.

Comment: How is the data stored then?  Seperate records for each?  If that's the case, you can alter what I have there to update the records, and blow away the ones you don't need anymore.